# Getting this error on RPI3 while launching pigpio

Tags: pigpio

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pigpio-master $ sudo pigpiod

2023-07-27 16:34:58 initMboxBlock: init mbox zaps failed
Can't initialise pigpio library
```

Pigpio version is 79

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to run pigpiod from a user directory (it is included in Raspberry Pi OS & Raspbian)?

Comment: The directory you run the command from doesn't matter. I assume @Milliways you mean "Why aren't you starting it as a service?" (which it is probably already running, since that is the default, and might be the cause of the problem).

Comment: @goldilocks I assume the OP is attempting to install pigpio. This is intended to be built & installed (and the instructions are reasonably clear). I have noted (when testing my own libraries) that running from the build directory often causes strange errors. `pigpiod` is normally started by the user; it can be started as a service but is not by default - it consumes significant resources.

Comment: I assumed it was enabled by default since the "vendor preset" is enabled; that it uses significant resources I imagine depends upon what it is doing, since on an idle 3B+ it occupies ~1K RSS and while it does `top` the list of active processes, it is only revving up one processor 5-20%.  Anyway, while *" I have noted (when testing my own libraries) that running from the build directory often causes strange errors"* is great, but tersely asking why someone would do something that is otherwise completely normal seems an attempt to waste everyone's time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.